# Can't show interstitial ads

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I am trying to include admob interstitials in a webview android App. My code hasn't any errors when I run my App, but any insterstitials ads appear. I've tried more codes, guides and no ads. Here's the code:

```
public class Interstitial extends Activity {

      private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

      /** Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
      private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

      }

      // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
      public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
          interstitialAd.show();
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: The summary says "progress dialog", but I don't see anything in your question that pertains to a progress dialog.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I wanted to ask something different but finally I find out the answer. My question is about interstitial ads

Answer (score 0):

I've made changes in my code. I added this after "//Create the interstitial":

```
//Set Ad Listener
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
              public void onAdLoaded(){
                   displayInterstitial();
              }
    });
```

Now it seems that is working, but I am not sure. Emulator doesn't show interstitials, but the logcat says "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to Access frame with URL googleads..... Domains, protocols and ports must match."

In a physical device, ads will work or I need to change something in my code?